# Remove Count Attribute in json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json data with count attribute I want to remove `"count":2` data from Json data.

Here is the Json data:

```
{"count":2,"value":[{"StudentId":"5","RollNo":"12228","StudentName":"Farhan","Attandance":"true"},{"StudentId":"6","RollNo":"443433","StudentName":"Arfan","Attandance":"False"}]}
```

I want to show like this - how is possible using jQuery?

```
[{"StudentId":"5","RollNo":"12228","StudentName":"Farhan","Attandance":"true"},{"StudentId":"6","RollNo":"443433","StudentName":"Arfan","Attandance":" False"}]
```

Here is my Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btnConvert').click(function () {
         $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(makeJsonFromTable('MyTable')))
         $('#result').show()

            var d = JSON.stringify(makeJsonFromTable('MyTable'));
            var d2 = d.value;

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("AddUser")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(value),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        })


    })
```

Comment: `delete your_obj["count"];`

Comment: can you plz tell me how dear?

Comment: @Aliyange553 you don't need us to tell you, you can find answers in many places already: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=oDPcW8q3JuydgAbfvajACw&q=javascript+delete+object+property&oq=javascript+delete+object+property&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0i7i30k1j0l7j0i30k1.3128.5191.0.5311.19.14.4.0.0.0.133.1283.10j4.14.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.12.910...0i13k1j0i13i30k1.0.04w-3TYlZ28

Answer (score 3):

Access that using `data.value;` where `data` is the original object:

```js
var data = {"count":2,"value":[{"StudentId":"5","RollNo":"12228","StudentName":"Farhan","Attandance":"true"},{"StudentId":"6","RollNo":"443433","StudentName":"Arfan","Attandance":"False"}]};
data = data.value;
console.log(data);
```